# unix command - ignore "The" while sorting

Tags: unix, command-line

I am listing directories and I would like to sort by name, but ignore leading "The", ie the output should be:

```
Apple
The Banana
Orange
```

and not

```
Apple
Orange
The Banana
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls | sed -e 's/^The \(.*\)/\1, The/' | sort | sed -e 's/\(.*\), The$/The \1/'
```

Comment: I really like this one. How could I adjust it a little so to only work within the first directory depth? "The Fruit/Apple" -> "Fruit, The/Apple"

Comment: Oh, getting there, I changed 's/^The \(.*\)/\1 to 's/^The \([^/]*\)/\1

Comment: find -mindepth 2 -type d | grep -o [^./].* | sed -e 's/^The \([^/]*\)/\1, The/' | sort | sed -e 's/\(.*\), The\//The \1\//'

Answer (score 2):

In fact I'm gonna put that in writing.

My suspicion is that the following will do what you want it to do:

```
ls -d * | sed 's/^The /\t/' | sort -b | sed 's/^\t/The /'
```

I'll explain. `ls -d *` lists all the directories. `sed -r 's/^The /\t/'` replaces all leading "The "s with tabs (a whitespace placeholder), `sort -b` sorts, ignoring leading whitespace (the tab), and `sed 's/^\t/The /'` replaces all those leading tabs with "The " again.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works, but is silly and won't work in every case (eg there are double spaces)

```
find . -type d | grep -o "[^./].*" | sed 's/^The/ /' | sort | sed 's/  /The /'
```

Comment: not really sure this works... the leading space you substitute in as a placeholder seems to cause all those directories to float to the top

Comment: ah. I tried to simplify things for the post. I'm stripping the leading ./ and only care about a leading The. Then I think the leading spaces are ignored. Editing now...

Comment: personally I prefer ... ls -d * | sed -r 's/^The /\t/' | sort -b | sed -r 's/^\t/The /' ... I believe this works

Comment: Yeah, I guess you won't find /t anywhere else in the filename. Of course, ls -d, ls -d -R, and find . -type d all give different results, so it really depends on what you want.