# How to "ignore" some strings with the sort Unix command?

Tags: sorting, unix

I'm hoping you can help me !

I have a auxiliary LaTeX file that I would like to sort alphabetically.

It looks like this :

```
blabla  ...

\textit {blablabla}  ...

\textit {bloublou}  ...

\textit {bleble} ... 

bloblo ... 

...
```

Is it possible to sort this file alphabetically, preserving the blank lines, ignoring  "\textit {", preserving it in the output?

So, for example, so that the sort command gives this output :

```
blabla  ...

\textit {blablabla}  ...

\textit {bleble} ... 

bloblo

\textit {bloublou}  ...

...
```

Thank you very much

Comment: oh ! i found my solution ! sorry, i would have to search more. I give the solution to help if someone have a same issue.
I found my solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4363605/6608121. The trick is to replace "\textit {" by a tab, then sort with "-b", then restore the "\textit {" expressions.
so : cat [...].tmp |  sed -e "s/\\\textit {/\t/" | sort -b | sed "s/^\t/\\\textit {/"

Comment: and, for the blank lines :
/
1 - first ignoring if blank line with : awk '$1' [...].tmp
/
2 - at the end, add blank line between each line  : sed -e 'G'

Comment: You should answer your own question with the complete solution:  schwartzian transform + reintroducing blank lines.